# URL redirection from 'More site stats on' link in Beta sites

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, beta-sites

In every beta site, we usually see the **Site Stats** side bar in the right hand side, at the end of side bar there is link for more stats in Stack Exchange site.

For an example: In **[Health beta](https://health.stackexchange.com/)** when hover the link it shows the URL as
[`stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#health`](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#health), click on that it will redirect to Stack Exchange All sites page.

[image: More site stats on]

But what is the use of the `#health` at end of the URL, it is expected to highlight the Health beta in the All sites page? or some other purpose?

Comment: Looks like a bug, the hash parameter is used to decide the sort, e.g. http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#users will sort by users.

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time (years ago) the design of the Sites list in stackexchange.com was different. Very different, and it supported auto scrolling to a specific site by having its name as the URL hash parameter.

Proof for this: https://web.archive.org/web/20110810010204/https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#physics (archive of the sites list from 2011)

Wait a bit, and you'll see how it scrolls down to physics site. (Health still didn't exist back then)

At some point, they changed the design and functionality, removing the ability to auto scroll to a specific site and instead using the hash parameter to let user sort the list by the various options, and SE team simply forgot to change the code in the beta sites "more stats" widget.